# Lualatex: several levels of subscripts in a sum

Tags: subscripts

I would like to have several subscripts in my sum, like "sum over all i but not for i = 3". I have tried using `\subscript` from `amsmath` but failed with `undefined control sequence`. I've also failed to use the `subarray` environment. Please tell me what is a step by step proper way to have several subscripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % amsmath plus some more features...

\begin{document}
\[\text{you may write }\sum_{i\mid i\neq 3} x_i\text{ or your idea } \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{over all }i\\\text{but not }i=3}}}x_i\]
\end{document}
```

[image]